# Check RabbitMQ queue size from client

Tags: .net, message-queue, rabbitmq, amqp

Does anyone know if there's a way to check the number of messages in a RabbitMQ queue from a client application?

I'm using the .NET client library.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You can actually retrieve this via the client.

When you perform a `queue_declare` operation, RabbitMQ returns a tuple with three values: `(<queue name>, <message count>, <consumer count>)`. The `passive` argument to `queue_declare` allows you to check whether a queue exists without modifying the server state, so you can use `queue_declare` with the `passive` option to check the queue length.

Not sure about .NET, but in Python, it looks something like this:

```python
name, jobs, consumers = chan.queue_declare(queue=queuename, passive=True)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, even if he did miss Basic.Get as the 2nd source of this info.

Comment: What is chan here and how to import it ?

Comment: This is no longer the best way to do it.

Comment: @Theyouthis It's very frustrating to find comments like "This is no longer the best way to do it" without any sort of reference to the improved way that you are referring to. Why not share your findings?

Comment: Use the MessageCount() function on your IModel. If you scroll down you will see two answers mention the function on this very question.

Comment: This is done differently nowadays: `result = channel.queue_declare(queue=queuename, passive=True).method`. And then you would just access `result.message_count` because the result is not unpackable. `<Queue.DeclareOk(['consumer_count=1', 'message_count=0', 'queue=xyz'])>`

Comment: Used this passive declaration in java for some time, but seems that lately it is so slow to update. I switched to http client requesting rabbit api, since it was not updating as it should (almost always it showed to have 0 total messages).

Answer (score 19):

I am 2 years too late but I was searching for it myself and found that rabbitmq gives u simple script to communicate to erlang nodes..its in sbin folder where the starting script for RabbitMQ is located..so you can basically say

```
./rabbitmqctl list_queues
```

this will display the queues along with the count of messages pending to those queues
similarly you can also say

```
./rabbitmqctl list_channels
./rabbitmqctl list_connections
```

etc.
For more info you can visit [here](http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html)

Answer (score 16):

If you want to do this in .NET, check which version of the client library you are using.

I'm using the **2.2.0** version and I had to use BasicGet(queue, noAck).
In this version of the library, QueueDeclare() only returns a string containing the queue name.

```
BasicGetResult result = channel.BasicGet("QueueName", false);
uint count = result != null ? result.MessageCount : 0;
```

I know from the **2.6.1** version, QueueDeclare() returns an object of type QueueDeclareOk.

```
QueueDeclareOk result = channel.QueueDeclare();
uint count = result.MessageCount;
```

Alternatively, you can call from the command line:

```
<InstallPathToRabbitMq>\sbin\rabbitmqctl.bat list_queues
```

And you see the following output:

> Listing queues...
> QueueName  1
> ...done.

Answer (score 9):

I'm using version **3.3.1** of the .NET client library.

I use the following, which is very similar to [Ralph Willgoss's second suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14733209), but you can supply the queue name as an argument.

```
QueueDeclareOk result = channel.QueueDeclarePassive(queueName);
uint count = result != null ? result.MessageCount : 0;
```

Answer (score 7):

my little snippet based on Myydrralls' answer. I think if he had code in his answer I might have noticed it much quicker.

```
public uint GetMessageCount(string queueName)
{
    using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())
    using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel())
    {
        return channel.MessageCount(queueName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the IModel's MessageCount method, documented here

http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-dotnet-client/v3.6.4/rabbitmq-dotnet-client-3.6.4-client-htmldoc/html/type-RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.html#method-M:RabbitMQ.Client.IModel.MessageCount(System.String)

edit: I know this is a very old post, but it is the first google response, and I hope it will help people looking for this answer in the future.

Comment: This is the first time I have seen this mentioned. Why is that?!!

Answer (score 5):

Update:  it appears that the pika implementation of queue_declare(..) has changed since mmalone's very helpful post.

In python/pika (v0.9.5) it's still possible to check the queue depth via pika, but it requires a slightly more indirect approach.

queue_declare(...) passes a method object into its callback function, which you can then inspect. For example, to check the number of messages and consumers in the queue named `'myQueue'`:

```
def cbInspect(qb):
    messagesInQueue = qb.method.message_count
    print "There are %d messages in myQueue" % messagesInQueue

    consumersInQueue = qb.method.consumer_count
    print "There are %d consumers in myQueue" % consumersInQueue

    return

myChannel = channel.queue_declare(callback=cbInspect, queue='myQueue', passive=True)
```

Hope this helps, and please go easy on me, I'm new around here :-)

Comment: channel.queue_declare returns an object that contains the current message count so if you want to avoid a callback, you can also access the message count like this: myChannel.method.message_count

Answer (score 5):

I was able to get the size/depth of queue from python program.

1. using py_rabbit

```
    from pyrabbit.api import Client
    cl = Client('10.111.123.54:15672', 'userid', 'password',5)
    depth = cl.get_queue_depth('vhost', 'queue_name')
```

2. kombu [a python package usually comes with celery installation]

```
conn = kombu.Connection('amqp://userid:password@10.111.123.54:5672/vhost')
conn.connect()
client = conn.get_manager()
queues = client.get_queues('vhost')
for queue in queues:
    if queue == queue_name:
    print("tasks waiting in queue:"+str(queue.get("messages_ready")))
    print("tasks currently running:"+str(queue.get("messages_unacknowledged")))
```

the ip address is just an example.

Edit:

3

I have found a better way to do this . curl appears to be more convenient and faster way to do it

```
curl -s -i -u $user:$password http://$host_ip_address:15672/api/queues/$vhost_name/$queue_name | sed 's/,/\n/g' | grep '"messages"' | sed 's/"messages"://g'
```

Answer (score 3):

At least as of RabbitMQ 3.3.5, you can do this in a C# program without any RabbitMQ client library by calling the RabbitMQ Management HTTP API:

```
// The last segment of the URL is the RabbitMQ "virtual host name". 
// The default virtual host name is "/", represented urlEncoded by "%2F".
string queuesUrl = "http://MY_RABBITMQ_SERVER:15672/api/queues/%2F";

WebClient webClient = new WebClient { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("MY_RABBITMQ_USERNAME", "MY_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD") };
string response = webClient.DownloadString(queuesUrl);
```

The username and password are the same as those you use to log into the RabbitMQ management console UI.

Response will be a JSON string with the list of queues, including their message counts, among other properties.  (If you like, you can deserialize that JSON into a C# object using a library like [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).)

The API documentation is installed along with the RabbitMQ management console and should be available on that server at http://MY_RABBITMQ_SERVER:15672/api .