# Retrieve queue length with Celery (RabbitMQ, Django)

Tags: django, queue, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm using Celery in a django project, my broker is RabbitMQ, and I want to retrieve the length of the queues. I went through the code of Celery but did not find the tool to do that. I found this issue on stackoverflow ([Check RabbitMQ queue size from client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038318/check-rabbitmq-queue-size-from-client)), but I don't find it satisfying.

Everything is setup in celery, so there should be some kind of magic method to retrieve what I want, without specifying a channel / connection.

Does anyone have any idea about this question ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example on how to read the queue length in rabbitMQ for a given queue:

```
def get_rabbitmq_queue_length(q):
    from pyrabbit.api import Client
    from pyrabbit.http import HTTPError

    count = 0

    try:
        cl = Client('localhost:15672', 'guest', 'guest')
        if cl.is_alive():
            count = cl.get_queue_depth('/', q)
    except HTTPError as e:
        print "Exception: Could not establish to rabbitmq http api: " + str(e) + " Check for port, proxy, username/pass configuration errors"
        raise

    return count
```

This is using [**pyrabbit**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyrabbit) as previously suggested by [Philip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2296812/philip-cristiano)

Comment: so no way through celery as is?

Comment: @FrederickNord, not that I am aware of. My understanding is that the workers ( Celery ) is only concerned with it's current task, or at most the task it pre-fetched (from RabbitMQ). It's unaware of what is in RabbitMQ and intentionally so.

Answer (score 3):

[PyRabbit](http://pyrabbit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is probably what you are looking for, it is a Python interface to the RabbitMQ management interface API. It will allow you to query for queues and their current message counts.

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the workers in celery by using `inspect` module. Here is the [guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html?highlight=revoke#inspecting-workers).

Also for `RabbitMQ` there are some [command line command](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/monitoring.html#rabbitmq).

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I don't need commands, I need python classes or methods. Plus, the inspect method will inspect the workers, not the queues, am I right ?

Comment: `inspect` **can not** retrieve the length of pending queue as I know. May be `inspect reserved`, but in my experience it doesn't help too..

Comment: Indeed, the official Celery documentation states that you inspect the queues with the rabbitmqctl command line tool. That is pretty inconvenient when RabbitMQ runs on a different machine.